# Appium - Developer Certificate issues

Tags: ios, testing, appium, ipa, ios-provisioning

my client is in onshore and he has given me an .IPA file provision profiled(with my device UDID) with developer certificate not with distribution(As mentioned in the appium docs).The problem is when I try to run the Appium code I'm getting "**Target failed to run.Permisson to debug [app name] was denied.The app must be signed with a development identity (i.e. iOS Developer)**" error. Any suggestions what might be the problem? And also please let me know.

1)Do i still need a developer account if i have a signed .ipa file?
2)While automation with appium, do I need any additional certificates from developers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is not from Appium, it is actually from Xcode. If you try the following steps, you will possibly see the same error message:

1. Install the app on the iPhone using the .ipa file.
2. Open the Xcode which is compatible with iOS version on the iPhone.
3. Right click on Xcode and open developer tools->Instruments.
4. Click on Automation and connect your device.Search for the Target app to be tested and click on record.
5. If the xcode is able to launch the app that means the app is properly signed and it can be used on xcode.Else it means it is not signed correctly.

If you can reproduce the above error with the steps, just show dev and let them know that their signature is not good.

Additionally,
  1).You do not need a developer account if you already have a signed ipa
  2).You also do not need any additional certificates from developers.